# Tag rename request: [dragonage-origins] -> [dragon-age-origins]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[dragonage-origins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonage-origins) (35 questions) -> [dragon-age-origins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-age-origins) (0 questions)

[The actual title of the game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age:_Origins) has a space between "Dragon" and "Age".

[Chat discussion.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/dragon-age-origins-tag-rename-discussion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes sense to me. If I don't get any opposition, I'll do a retag and create a synonym.

Since this is just a rename, this is also easily reversible post-retag, as well.