# Tag rename request: [harddrive] → [hard-drive]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

**Hard drive** is two words, and the tag should reflect this. So I'd like to request that [harddrive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harddrive) be renamed/made a synonym of [hard-drive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive).

See also:

- [Tag rename request: [dragonage-origins] -> [dragon-age-origins]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1637/tag-rename-request-dragonage-origins-dragon-age-origins)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but since this was completed, can you accept an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been done. Good spot.