# Tag rename request: [skyforce2014] -> [sky-force-2014]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Sky Force 2014 are separate words, according to the [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.skyforcehd&hl=en).

See also:

- [Tag rename request: [harddrive] → [hard-drive]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/tag-rename-request-harddrive-%E2%86%92-hard-drive?rq=1)
- [Tag rename request: [dragonage-origins] -> [dragon-age-origins]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1637/tag-rename-request-dragonage-origins-dragon-age-origins)

**edit**:

I tried to change it, but I cannot make the new tag:

[image: Not able to change tag]

Can a mod fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've gone and made that change for you - so now all of the questions are now tagged with [sky-force-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sky-force-2014), and the old tag has been merged into this new one as a synonym.